# height of regular sequence modulo minimal prime

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Liu Qing's book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves has the following statement on 6.3.11:

Let $Y$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and $i \colon X \to Y$ a regular immersion of codimension $n$. Then for every irreducible component $Y_i$ of $Y$, then $\mathrm{codim}(X\cap Y_i, Y_i) = n$ provided $X \cap Y_i \ne \emptyset $.

After passage to localization, the statement may be reformulated as follows:

Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring with regular sequence $x_1,\dots, x_n$. For any minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $A$, we have $\operatorname{ht}((x_1,\dots,x_n) \mod \mathfrak{q}) = n$ in the ring $A/\mathfrak{q}$.

For $n = 1$ this is exactly Krull's principal ideal theorem. The book claims that one can prove the general statement by induction on $n$ but I can't quite see the issue.

Comment: Set $J_i := (x_1, \ldots, x_i)A/\mathfrak{q}$. By induction $\operatorname{ht}(J_{n-1}) = n-1$, so every minimal prime of $J_{n-1}$ has height $n-1$, and does not contain $x_n$. Thus every minimal prime of $J_n$ has height $> n - 1$, i.e. $\operatorname{ht}(J_n) = n$